# EF 4.0 Logging Changes on an Entity using an overrided savechanges method

Tags: logging, entity-framework-4

I was wondering if there was a generic way to log changes/additions/deletions for each object using EF 4.0.
I know you can override the  int SaveChanges(SaveOptions options) method but i'm not sure what i should put in there.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logging every data change with Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295710/logging-every-data-change-with-entity-framework)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle [SavingChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savingchanges.aspx) event on your context and use context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState) to get information about changes. This method returns enumeration of [ObjectStateEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstateentry.aspx) which contains information about changes.

Comment: How would i access a generated id for a new insert within the savingchanges method?

Comment: You can't get Id in SaveChanges, because Id is generated by database AFTER SaveChanges.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used found [here](https://exceptionnotfound.net/entity-change-tracking-using-dbcontext-in-entity-framework-6/) I modified it because it didn't work

```
private object GetPrimaryKeyValue(DbEntityEntry entry)
        {
            var objectStateEntry = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entry.Entity);
            object o = objectStateEntry.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value;
            return o;
        }

         private bool inExcludeList(string prop)
        {
            string[] excludeList = { "props", "to", "exclude" };
            return excludeList.Any(s => s.Equals(prop));
        }

        public int SaveChanges(User user, string UserId)
        {
            var modifiedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
                .Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();
            var now = DateTime.Now;

            foreach (var change in modifiedEntities)
            {

                var entityName = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(change.Entity.GetType()).Name;
                var primaryKey = GetPrimaryKeyValue(change);
                var DatabaseValues = change.GetDatabaseValues();

                foreach (var prop in change.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
                {
                    if(inExcludeList(prop))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    string originalValue = DatabaseValues.GetValue<object>(prop)?.ToString();
                    string currentValue = change.CurrentValues[prop]?.ToString();

                    if (originalValue != currentValue)
                    {
                        ChangeLog log = new ChangeLog()
                        {
                            EntityName = entityName,
                            PrimaryKeyValue = primaryKey.ToString(),
                            PropertyName = prop,
                            OldValue = originalValue,
                            NewValue = currentValue,
                            ModifiedByName = user.LastName + ", " + user.FirstName,
                            ModifiedById = UserId,
                            ModifiedBy = user,
                            ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now
                        };

                        ChangeLogs.Add(log);
                    }
                }
            }
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }



public class ChangeLog 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string EntityName { get; set; }
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }
        public string PrimaryKeyValue { get; set; }
        public string OldValue { get; set; }
        public string NewValue { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedByName { get; set; }



        [ForeignKey("ModifiedBy")]
        [DisplayName("Modified By")]
        public string ModifiedById { get; set; }
        public virtual User ModifiedBy { get; set; }


        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    }
```