# Delete trigger for audit table

Tags: sql-server, triggers, audit

I'm working on a web application that executes CRUD operations on some table in a SQL Server database. There will be a logged user in the application executing these operations.

(By the way, I'm using Entity Framework)

Let's say table is

**MyTable**

- MyTableId
- SomeColumn
- LastModifiedUserId
- LastModifiedDate

And I a have an audit table like

**MyTableHistory**

- MyTableHistoryId
- MyTableId
- SomeColumn
- ActionType  --ins/upd/del
- ActionUserId
- ActioDate

And I'm using triggers to insert data on the audit table.

Inserts and updates are easy by consulting the Inserted and Updated tables to find the userid who modified the record.

But what about deletes? Any idea how I might get that info?

Comment: there is the `INSERTED` pseudo table, as you said, but not an `UPDATED` one. There's the `DELETED` pseudo table too

Comment: But DELETED will simply have the LastModifiedUserId that last updated the record, not the one who deleted the record. That's the one I want

Comment: `suser_sname()` is the account name who run the query.

Comment: `suser_sname()` will only return the login for the whatever account connected to SQL Server. If it is being used by a web service, it won't identify the end user.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `updated` table. The two pseudo tables available in DML triggers are `inserted` and `deleted`. In the case of `insert` table `deleted` is empty, in the case of `delete` table `inserted` is empty, in the case of `update` both tables are populated.
You can create three separate triggers for each action (to distinguish `ActionType`) or try to combine all in one trigger.
**Note:** take into account multiple row actions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using EF to add the information about which user is updating records, the easiest way to capture that information is to have EF perform a 2-step process (UPDATE, DELETE) on the data you wish to delete. You will then need to interpret the two audit rows as part of the same operation.

There is a much more involved solution that "might" work, but I have not tested it. There is more information available below if you wish to explore it.

- [Blog describing the solution](http://blogs.msmvps.com/p3net/2013/09/13/entity-framework-and-user-context/)
- [Stack Overflow post of someone trying it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426651/context-info-lost-while-executing-entity-framework-savechanges-overload)

Another option altogether is to abandon trigger auditing (which is problematic for this very reason) and use Entity Framework instead. Below is an example of how one might accomplish this by overriding the `SaveChanges` method:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry> ChangedEntries()
{
    return ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x =>
        x.State == EntityState.Added ||
        x.State == EntityState.Deleted ||
        x.State == EntityState.Modified);
}

public virtual int SaveChanges(string userName)
{
    var changes = ChangedEntries();

    foreach (var entry in changes)
    {
        var eventType = entry.State == EntityState.Added ? "A" : entry.State == EntityState.Deleted ? "D" : "U";
        var entityType = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(entry.Entity.GetType()).Name;

        var oldValues = entry.State == EntityState.Added ? null : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry.OriginalValues.ToObject());
        var newValues = entry.State == EntityState.Deleted ? null : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry.CurrentValues.ToObject());

        oldValues = oldValues?.Substring(0, Math.Min(oldValues.Length, 4000));
        newValues = newValues?.Substring(0, Math.Min(newValues.Length, 4000));

        AuditItems.Add(
            new AuditItem
            {
                EventTime = DateTime.Now,
                UserName = userName,
                EntityType = entityType,
                EventType = eventType,
                OldValues = oldValues,
                NewValues = newValues
            }
        );
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```